# adding url parameters to grails form

Tags: grails

I have a form and want to add customer URL parameters , for example in the classical "create"

```
http://localhost:8080/test/customer/create?abc=asd
```

I changed the form from POST to GET, both in the view file 
method="GET" and in the controller, remove the allowedMethods

Still the custom parameter "abc" is not inserted from the view to the action, it does not appear in the params - params.abc is null

the show action works

```
http://localhost:8080/grails/copyOfLead/show/3?abc=asd
```

works....

Comment: likely there is something wrong with your form. Have you set the name on your input field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to read the parameter in the create and pass it to the save

```
def create() {
        def newLead = new Lead(params)
        newLead.urlParams  = params.abc
        respond newLead
    }
```

And then in the save its added automatically

```
@Transactional
    def save(Lead leadInstance) {
   .......
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right you have to add hidden field to your form

```
<g:hiddenField name="abc" value="${params.abc}" />
```